# Mouse position inside WPF Canvas

Tags: wpf, mouse, cursor-position

I'm working on a tiny color picker in WPF. I have this...

```
                <Border
                    Background="Transparent"
                    BorderBrush="Black"
                    BorderThickness="2"
                    SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                    <Canvas x:Name="ColorPlaneCanvas"
                        Width="400"
                        Height="400"
                        Background="Transparent"
                        MouseLeftButtonDown="{s:Action PlanePositionChanged}"
                        MouseMove="{s:Action PlanePositionChanged}"
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <Ellipse x:Name="ColorPlane"
                            Canvas.Left="{Binding PlaneX}"
                            Canvas.Top="{Binding PlaneY}"
                            Width="10"
                            Height="10"
                            Fill="Transparent"
                            SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                            Stroke="White"
                            StrokeThickness="2" />
                    </Canvas>
                </Border>
```

I use a canvas (on top of another canvas), which contains a little "plane". When I drag the mouse on the top canvas, the plane's coordinates updates, as `MouseLeftButtonDown` event gets called.

**But if I move the mouse to the Canvas'side (any side, which is not part of the canvas, but the containing elements), I can still get the `MouseLeftButtonDown` event.**

*What can I do to get the mouse event only within the Canvas?*

[Here](https://drive.joex.hu/index.php/s/FjQzfZn9ddxh6eN) is a working version, if you want to see the artifact.

Comment: "Canvas's side"? Please clarify.

Comment: All sides. Top, bottom, left, right. It seems like it's size is bigger than 400px(I specified that in XAML)

Answer (score 0):

i did a similar program that tells u the cords of the mouse in the canvas and if u click it paints a line, ill send u the wpf and the code, see if it helps, i use a point and it works.

WPF:

```
<Canvas x:Name="cnvPaper" Background="Aquamarine" Margin="30" MouseEnter="cnvPaper_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="cnvPaper_MouseLeave" MouseDown="cnvPaper_MouseDown" MouseMove="cnvPaper_MouseMove"/>
```

C#

```
    Point previousPoint;

        private void cnvPaper_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
              previousPoint = e.GetPosition(cnvPaper);
        }

        private void cnvPaper_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            String cordsText = "X: " + e.GetPosition(cnvPaper).X + " - Y: " + e.GetPosition(cnvPaper).Y;
            if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
            {
                DrawLine(e.GetPosition(cnvPaper));
            }
            else if(e.RightButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
            {
                DrawCircle(e.GetPosition(cnvPaper));
            }
            previousPoint = e.GetPosition(cnvPaper);
        }
```